# Laravel excel 3.1problem Blank page when Import file

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-excel

### Package: maatwebsite/excel 3.1

He worked with me normally until some problems began. 
The problem when i import excel file, nothing result or error. only blank page.
if add redirect code after importing, he redirect me to without data.

i cant find the problem, because i check my code & test to dump the row `dump($row)` but the same problem is a Blank page!
I tried to delete the package and then reinstall it the same problem.
You also check the database and the controllers and work Successfully

`Imports/WordsImport`:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\WordsList;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;

class WordsImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if (!isset($row[0])) {
            return null;
        }

        return new WordsList([

            'Translation'    => $row[1],
            'EnglishPos'     => $row[2],
            'EnglishWave'    => $row[3],
            'Word'           => $row[4],
            'SimpleWords'    => $row[5],
            'ArabicPos'      => $row[6],
            'ArabicWave'     => $row[7],
            'ArabicSense'    => $row[8],
            'Synonyms'       => $row[9],
            'Antonyms'       => $row[10]

        ]);
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 10000000000;
    }
}
```

`Controller .. /ImportWordsController`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Imports\WordsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;


class ImportWordsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('ImportWords');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'select_file'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx',
        ]);

        Excel::import(new WordsImport, request()->file('select_file'));


        //return redirect('/dashboard/wordslist')
        //          ->with('success','The word has been Uploaded successfully');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```